# Can't create resource group via Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to create one resource group via PowerShell.

I am using below command to achieve that:

```
 New-AzResourceGroup -Name "RG01" -Location "Central US"
```

I am following this Microsoft document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroup?view=azps-7.5.0

I have Az module installed in my PowerShell. Still I'm getting below error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I am very new to Azure and PowerShell.

Comment: Did you try running the command it suggested? It will probably tell you more about what's not working. "run `Import-Module Az.Resources`"

Comment: Now. this error coming: Import-Module : File C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Az.Resources\5.6.0\MSGraph.Autorest\Az.MSGraph.psm1 
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
about_Execution_Policies

Comment: @user_50520, Based on the above error message in your previous comment. Your PowerShell execution policy is blocking to execute the script. I would suggest you refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1) and change the execution policy based on your requirement. Post changing the policy try re-running the script again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the execution policy of RemoteSigned for current user scope (Administrator Privileges).

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Import Az Resources Module

```
Import-Module Az.Resources
```

Execute Az Module Command for Resource Group creation.

```
New-AzResourceGroup -Name "RG01" -Location "Central US"
```

### Execution Policy Type

**Restricted (Default)** - No Script either local, remote or downloaded can be executed on the system.
**AllSigned** - All script that are ran require to be digitally signed.
**RemoteSigned** - All remote scripts (UNC) or downloaded need to be signed.
**Unrestricted** - No signature for any type of script is required.

### Scope of new Change

**LocalMachine (Default)** - The execution policy affects all users of the computer.
**CurrentUser** - The execution policy affects only the current user.
**Process** - The execution policy affects only the current Windows PowerShell process.

Comment: Tqs for clarifying.... It's working :)